How to reverse legend order without affecting bar order in Plotly R?
I am creating a stacked bar chart using Plotly in R, and the order of the items in the legend is the reverse of the order that I want.
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(forcats)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  institution = c('Four-year colleges', 'Two-year colleges', 'Nonprofit organizations', 'Other'),
  percentage = c(27,22,30,31)
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(institution = fct_reorder(institution, percentage, .desc = TRUE))

color_palette = c('#245075', '#B03E61', '#BD4C42', '#4B7F60')

fig2 <- df
fig2 <- fig2 %>% plot_ly(
  x = ~percentage, y = ~factor(1),  type = 'bar',
  color = ~institution,
  colors = color_palette,
  text = ~paste0(percentage, '%'),
  textfont = list(color = 'white'), 
  height = 170
)

fig2 <- fig2 %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(
    title = '',
    showticklabels = FALSE,
    showgrid = FALSE,
    zeroline = FALSE,
    showline = FALSE
  ),
  xaxis = list(
    title = '',
    showticklabels = FALSE,
    showgrid = FALSE,
    zeroline = FALSE,
    showline = FALSE
  ),
  barmode = 'stack',
  showlegend = TRUE,
  legend = list(orientation = 'h')
)
fig2 <- fig2 %>%config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
fig2

stacked bar chart
I tried reversing the factor order. Although this fixes the order of the legend, it causes the stacked bar chart and colors to be inverted.
df <- df %>% mutate(institution = fct_reorder(institution, percentage, .desc = FALSE))
stacked bar chart 2

Just found it in this forum Fixing plotly legend order
It's ridiculous because nowhere in the plotly documentation does it talk about traceorder.
legend = list(orientation = 'h', traceorder = 'normal')

